# Generate tree from Python list of list

Tags: python

I have the following Python list:

```
[
  ['a.b.c.d.e.rollover', 0],
  ['a.b.c.d.e.f.rollover', 1],
  ['a.b.c.d.e.g.rollover', 0]
]
```

Suppose this list is extremely large (lots of elements !)

**Is there an efficient way in Python to convert this into a multi-level dictionary like the following ?**

```
{
  'a': {
     'b': {
        'c': {
           'd': {
              'e': {
                 'rollover': 0,
                 'f': {
                    'rollover': 1
                 }
                 'g': {
                    'rollover': 0
                 }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the "following Format" a String or a list?

Comment: Just curious, why?. Really, why?

Comment: The 'following format' is a Python list.
Regarding the why: why not ? This is required for my application, that's why.

Comment: Some kind of homework or something?

Comment: what's the first element of the first inner list? look carefully. you either missed . for a comma or quotations

Comment: Missed quotations ... fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `lambda` that returns `defaultdict` that uses the same `lambda`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
  ['a.b.c.d.e.rollover', 0],
  ['a.b.c.d.e.f.rollover', 1],
  ['a.b.c.d.e.g.rollover', 0]
]

dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)
res = dd()

for k, v in l:
    d = res
    keys = k.split('.')

    # Add all the keys except the last one, d[x] will do since 
    # it forces default value to be generated
    for x in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[x]

    # Assign value to last key
    d[keys[-1]] = v

print res['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['rollover'] # 0
print res['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']['f']['rollover'] # 1
```

**Short explanation:** In order to automatically generate a new `defaultdict` in case that key doesn't exist we need a function (or `lambda`) that returns such an object. Since `defaultdict` constructor needs a parameter we have to provide a function that passes the parameter to `defaultdict`. Every time that non-existing key is being dereferenced the function is called and it creates a new `defaultdict` that will again call the same function in the future if required. This is called [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).

Comment: Nice. Can I ask what the lambda part does ? I've never seen a lambda construction like this.

Comment: `lambda` simply returns `defaultdict` that uses the same `lambda` to generate default value. Since missing keys default to `dict` it allows assignments like `d['a']['b']['c'] = 'foobar'`.

Comment: A `lambda` just defines a function concisely, as an expression. You could use `def dd(): return defaultdict(dd)` and get the same result.

Comment: Ok, so in this case it serves the purpose of autovivification.

Comment: @OlivierCervello: Yes, exactly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) has a Python example just like this.